# Storing usernames and user IDs in a Python dictionary using a for loop

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a DB of usernames (usernames) and user ID's (uid). I want to store these in a python dictionary so I can look-up someone's username based on their uid.

I'm able to successfully connect to and read the db using psycopg2, which I'm calling 'query_results'. The uid value is in the 0th table column and the corresponding username at 4, such that:

```
for each in query_results:
       uid=each[0]
       username=each[4]
```

I now want to iterate over query_results to create a dictionary, called userNames.

I have it structured like so:

```
userNames={"data":{}}

for each in query_results:
    uid=each[0]
    username=each[4]
    userNames["data"][uid]=uid
    userList["data"][username]=username
```

This is not working unfortunately and I think it's because I don't have my dictionary structured the right way and/or I don't have the for loop structrued properly.

Ideally, I'd like to have it set-up where the uid is a key, and the value is the username. So for example, if I call userNames[12] . . . I get 'StanTheMan'.

How do I set this up the right way?

Comment: Why have a database if you're gonna store them in a dict?

Comment: Use psycopg2's `DictCursor`: https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#psycopg2.extras.DictCursor

Answer (score 0):

Your code is mapping the username to the username, and the uid to the uid, so you can't use it to look anythinng up. You should map the uid to the username.

```
for each in query_results:
    uid=each[0]
    username=each[4]
    userNames["data"][uid]=username
```